# Method checking to prove the below statement regarding a function and its inverse

Tags: functions, inverse

> If a function "$f$" has a inverse and given that there is a point $x= a$ (lying in the domain of $f$) such that $f(a) = b$ , $a\neq b$ and $f^{-1}(a) = f(a)$ .  Show that $f(x)$ is a self-inverse function.              And from that then show that only in case of **non self inverse function** is the following holds:  for some $z \in dom(f)$ and which satisfies $f^{-1}(x) = f(x)$ then $f(x) = x$ must be satisfied for that $z$.

My method was  as the function is having a point which satisfy $f(a) = b$, that implies $f^{-1}(b) =a$ and also $f(b) = a$, from the condition $f^{-1}(a) = b$.  So we got another solution to $f^{-1}(x) = f(x)$ that is $b$, which doesn't satisfy $f(b) = b$. Hence if $(a,b)$ is a point on $(x,f(x))$ then $(b,a)$ is a point on $(x,f(x))$ too, so hence the graph is symmetric about $y = x$, hence concluded it's a self inverse function. The later part can be showed by just taking the complement of the statement stated in first part proving?

**Note** : Although I think we need to have one more condition that $b$ is in the domain of $f$ for the first statement to be true at all.